# How to select and export the large data in big database to excel - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, bigdata

**My task is selecting and exporting a large monitoring data from database ** 
My database have two big tables to store monitoring data. 
 - Table *MonitoringDataInfo* (~60M rows): have some fields **id (pk), stationId, createdAt** and one group index (**stationId** asc, **createdAt** desc) 
 - Table *MonitoringData* (~300M rows): have some fields **id (pk), dataId, indicator, value, unit** and one group index (**dataId** asc, **indicator** asc) 
 (**id** of *MonitoringDataInfo* is foreign key of **dataId** of *MonitoringData*) 
 I do a query below:

```
SELECT
  [Info].[id], [Info].[sentAt], [Data].[id] AS [Data.id], [Data].[indicator] AS [Data.indicator], [Data].[value] AS [Data.value]
FROM
  [monitoring_data_info] AS [Info]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  [monitoring_data] AS [Data]
    ON [Info].[id] = [Data].[dataId]
WHERE
      [Info].[stationId] = N'EKTjhVrZibUE7h55b6tu'
  AND [Info].[createdAt] BETWEEN N'2021-10-07 07:14:51.000 +00:00' AND N'2021-10-14 07:14:51.000 +00:00'
ORDER BY
  [Info].[createdAt] ASC;
```

==> This query return **69253** rows after more than **10** minutes. 
 
 My Questions are:
 - How should I do to optimize the execution time as well as database?  
 Thanks in advand!

Comment: Please generate the explain plan for this query and include it in your question.

Comment: Are you ***certain*** this is right?  `ON [Info].[id] = [Data].[dataId]`  Either it's a mistake or the `dataId` column is badly named *(it implies that it refers to itself, not the info table)*.

Comment: @MatBailie It's right because  it return the results.

Comment: Is "group inde" an Excel term?

Comment: @RickJames No, It's not. It's a database index. I just edit to remove Excel from the question.

Comment: Which database?  MySQL does not use square brackets.

Comment: @RickJames this is MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on either of below columns

```
    id, stationId, createdAt, sentAt column of 
    monitoring_data_info table

   and  dataId column of monitoring_data table
```

depending upon the data you can have your indexes made especially on joined columns and where clause columns

Also, Dont overload the indexes too as i could see you have grouped index though it includes the necessary column but additional column in the group index may have cause to resort the data likewise would recommend to have index on just joined columns and sentAt as per your recent edit

Comment: I just edit my post to replace 'sentAt' to 'createdAt'. I already have a group index (stationId asc, createdAt desc) on MonitoringDataInfo table. So do you mean I should have a further an index for only column 'createdAt' ?

Answer (score 0):

Is that query in Excel?

It might be faster to export the two sheets into database tables with minimal conversion or querying.  Then do the Joining/Grouping in the database engine, which is more optimized for such.

Comment: No, It's the query in the database. I just edit my question to remove Excel